# How do I know an array of structures was allocated in the Large Object Heap (LOH) in .NET?

Tags: .net, arrays, large-object-heap

After some experimenation using CLR Profiler, I found that:

```
Node[,] n = new Node[100,23]; //'84,028 bytes, is not placed in LOH
Node[,] n = new Node[100,24]; //'86,428 bytes, is 

    public struct Node {
        public int Value;
        public Point Point;
        public Color Color;
        public bool Handled;
        public Object Tag;
    }
```

During run-time, how do I know an array of structures (or any array) was allocated in the Large Object Heap (LOH)?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible (without using the profiling API yourself). Why do you want to know?

Comment: I am having performance issues with one structure used by an application. I have successfully optimized other arrays (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762424/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-initialize-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-non-default-va/). Yet, this structure is the real performance killer.

Comment: If it's just for performance tuning, then why not just use the profiler as you have been?

Answer (score 2):

Any object larger than 85,000 bytes will be stored on the LOH. Here is a great blog post about [.Net Memory Management](http://blogs.msdn.com/johan/archive/2007/04/20/memory-management-in-the-net-framework.aspx).

Comment: for double[] the limit currently (.NET RT 4.0) lays at 8k

Answer (score 2):

You can find out right after allocation. Use the GC.GetGeneration(object) overload to get the generation number, the object lays in. For LOH this will be 2.

```
Node[,] n = new Node[100,23]; 
// GC.GetGeneration(n) should give 0
Node[,] n = new Node[100,24]; 
// GC.GetGeneration(n) should give 2
```

Note, this comes with some restrictions and is by no means a proper way for production code, I assume: If you query that number at a later point, the object may has been moved from Gen 0 up to Gen 2 already. There is no way I know of to distinguish between the Gen2 (small object) heap and LOH. Also, the number returned for objects on the LOH is 2 for all .NET versions I did test it with. But I couldn't find this in a real specification, so it may be a matter of change as well.

Comment: +1 for innovative thinking. Nice. Clever. Something I should have thought of.  I will give this a try later.

Comment: @AMissico: thanks! good to know, you like it (even if the +1 didn't arrive ;) )

Comment: @user492238: You will earn the actual vote when I verify your answer. :O)

Comment: @AMissico: well, I will not beg for it ;) but usually the '+1' means just a vote up. When the answer could be verified, this would rather qualify it to be the "correct solution" :)

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, I don't think you actually need to know whether the object is going to go on the LOH or not. Whether or not that's the actual cause of your application's slowdown is kind of irrelevant when all you really want to do is display a warning to the user when they enter a value that's "too big".

So I would suggest something a bit simpler: just use a bit of trial-and-error to determine the cut-off value. If they enter a size over your trial-and-error value, display the warning.

As for your actual performance problems, instead of allocating one big two-dimensional array, you could simply allocate a bunch of "smaller" one dimensional arrays. Instead of:

```
Node[,] n = new Node[100,100]; // this will go the LOH
```

You'd do this:

```
Node[][] n = new Node[100][];
for(int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++) {
    n[i] = new Node[100];  // none of these will be on the LOH
}
```

You'd still have the same number of nodes in total, but nothing would go on the LOH. Personally, I think you will probably find that the performance is actually not going to be all that much different, but it might be worthwhile to just give it a try.